# XSLTForm date picker not displayed correctly

Tags: xforms, xsltforms

The display of the XSLTForms date picker sometimes appears distorted and/or misaligned.

Comment: sorry this little information is completely unacceptable for a question. I flag for closure. For guidance please read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Posted as Q&A. I deliberately answered my own question. Both the question and the answers (including one by the author of XSLTForms) are helpful to the user community, please leave it as is.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed! This can easily be fixed by renaming those classes in XSLTForms: it will be committed in the next release.

Answer (score 1):

The date picker is styled by CSS and has classes like name, day, weekend etc.
If you have used those in your own markup then any CSS styling you apply to them will unintentionally be applied to the date picker and can cause such distortions.